# Trigger for insert, delete, update returning old & new value in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

So i have got a table called *parts* with the columns *PartID, PartName, PartColor, PartPrice, PartCity* and I want to create a trigger that returns the old and new values via **.put_line** when *inserting* and *updating* and return the old value when *deleting.*

I want to do this all with one trigger.

I wrote this trigger, which isn't working:

> (PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DELETING'
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSERTING')

```
create or replace trigger parts_aft_upd_ins_del
after update or insert or delete
on parts
for each row
begin
    if updating then
        dbms_output.put_line('Triggered by UPDATE');
        
        if updating('PartID') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartID) || ' NEW:  ' ||
                         trim(:new.PartID));
                         
        elsif updating('PartName') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartName) || ' NEW:  ' ||
                         trim(:new.PartName));
                        
        elsif updating('PartColor') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartColor) || ' NEW:  ' ||
                         trim(:new.PartColor));
                         
        elsif updating('PartPrice') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartPrice) || ' NEW:  ' ||
                         trim(:new.PartPrice)); 
                         
        elsif updating('PartCity') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartCity) || ' NEW:  ' ||
                         trim(:new.PartCity)); 
        
        else
             dbms_output.put_line('Old & New values unknown.');  
        
        end if;
        
    elsif deleting then
        dbms_output.put_line('Triggered by DELETE');
        
        if deleting('PartID') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartID) ||);
                         
        elsif deleting('PartName') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartName));
                       
        elsif deleting('PartColor') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartColor));
                         
        elsif deleting('PartPrice') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartPrice)); 
                         
        elsif deleting('PartCity') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartCity)); 
        
        else
             dbms_output.put_line('Old values unknown.');  
        
        end if;
    elsif inserting then
        dbms_output.put_line('Triggered by INSERT');
        
        if inserting('PartID') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartID) || ' NEW:  ' ||
                         trim(:new.PartID));
                         
        elsif inserting('PartName') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartName) || ' NEW:  ' ||
                         trim(:new.PartName));
                        
        elsif inserting('PartColor') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartColor) || ' NEW:  ' ||
                         trim(:new.PartColor));
                         
        elsif inserting('PartPrice') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartPrice) || ' NEW:  ' ||
                         trim(:new.PartPrice)); 
                         
        elsif inserting('PartCity') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartCity) || ' NEW:  ' ||
                         trim(:new.PartCity)); 
        
        else
             dbms_output.put_line('Old & New values unknown.');  
        
        end if;
        
    else 
        dbms_output.put_line('Trigger "parts_aft_upd_ins_del" unknown error.');
    end if;
end;
/
show errors
```

Do you have any idea how I am able to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't use so many `IF else..` just use `IF updating` and all `dbms_output` that you want while table is updated and same for deleting

Comment: @Popeye Yeah I will post my fixed code in a sec.. The if statements while updating I made cause I dont know what column will be updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are deleting the whole **row**, so there's no point in e.g. `deleting('PartID')`. Use `deleting` only.

Comment: that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors in your trigger.

- `deleting`/`inserting` do not take any parameters. They are booleans.
- While inserting `:old` values are always null and while deleting `:new` values are always null.

Use the following code where both of the above issues are resolved.

```
create or replace trigger parts_aft_upd_ins_del
after update or insert or delete
on parts
for each row
begin
    if updating then
        dbms_output.put_line('Triggered by UPDATE');
        dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' || trim(:old.PartID) || ' NEW: ' || trim(:new.PartID));
        dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' || trim(:old.PartName) || ' NEW:  ' || trim(:new.PartName));
        dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' || trim(:old.PartColor) || ' NEW:  ' || trim(:new.PartColor));
        dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' || trim(:old.PartPrice) || ' NEW:  ' || trim(:new.PartPrice)); 
        dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' || trim(:old.PartCity) || ' NEW:  ' || trim(:new.PartCity));       
    elsif deleting then
        dbms_output.put_line('Triggered by DELETE');
        dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' || trim(:old.PartID) ||);
        dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' || trim(:old.PartName));
        dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' || trim(:old.PartColor));
        dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' || trim(:old.PartPrice)); 
        dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' || trim(:old.PartCity));        
    elsif inserting then
        dbms_output.put_line('Triggered by INSERT');
        dbms_output.put_line(' NEW:  ' || trim(:new.PartID));
        dbms_output.put_line( ' NEW:  ' || trim(:new.PartName));
        dbms_output.put_line( ' NEW:  ' || trim(:new.PartColor));
        dbms_output.put_line(' NEW:  ' || trim(:new.PartPrice)); 
        dbms_output.put_line(' NEW:  ' || trim(:new.PartCity)); 
    end if;    
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Littlefoot for pointing out my logic error.

The code now works just fine:

```
create or replace trigger parts_aft_upd_ins_del
after update or insert or delete
on parts
for each row
begin
    if updating then
        dbms_output.put_line('Triggered by UPDATE');
        
        if updating('PartID') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartID) || ' NEW:  ' ||
                         trim(:new.PartID));
                         
        elsif updating('PartName') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartName) || ' NEW:  ' ||
                         trim(:new.PartName));
                        
        elsif updating('PartColor') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartColor) || ' NEW:  ' ||
                         trim(:new.PartColor));
                         
        elsif updating('PartPrice') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartPrice) || ' NEW:  ' ||
                         trim(:new.PartPrice)); 
                         
        elsif updating('PartCity') then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD: ' ||
                         trim(:old.PartCity) || ' NEW:  ' ||
                         trim(:new.PartCity)); 
        
        else
             dbms_output.put_line('Old & New values unknown.');  
        
        end if;
        
    elsif deleting then
        dbms_output.put_line('Triggered by DELETE');
        
        if deleting() then
            dbms_output.put_line('OLD PartID: ' || trim(:old.PartID) || 
                                 ' OLD PartName: ' || trim(:old.PartName) ||
                                 ' OLD PartColor: ' || trim(:old.PartColor) || 
                                 ' OLD PartPrice: ' || trim(:old.PartPrice) ||
                                 ' OLD PartCity: ' || trim(:old.PartCity)
                                 );
                         
        else
             dbms_output.put_line('Old values unknown.');  
        
        end if;
    elsif inserting then
        dbms_output.put_line('Triggered by INSERT');
        
        if inserting() then
            dbms_output.put_line('NEW PartID: ' || trim(:new.PartID) || 
                                 ' NEW PartName: ' || trim(:new.PartName) ||
                                 ' NEW PartColor: ' || trim(:new.PartColor) || 
                                 ' NEW PartPrice: ' || trim(:new.PartPrice) ||
                                 ' NEW PartCity: ' || trim(:new.PartCity)
                                 );
        
        else
             dbms_output.put_line('New values unknown.');  
        
        end if;
        
    else 
        dbms_output.put_line('Trigger "parts_aft_upd_ins_del" unknown error.');
    end if;
end;
/
show errors
```